# ssh limit sent ciphers

Tags: ssh, encryption

I have an issue that I cannot connect with ubuntu focal (in a container) to a server behind a palo alto
It works with xenial and bionic
The difference we see there is the Cipher sent for key exchange

I wanted to test with the same ciphers, but there comes my issue:
Neither with

> Cipher ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa

in /etc/ssh/ssh_config
nor with

> -o Cipher=ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa

( I tested both also only with one Cipher as option)

You see in both cases via wireshark dump that all Ciphers are sent.
How do you restrict sending the ciphers at all

Answer (score 0):

You can add the Ciphers configuration into your users ssh/config file
e.g.

```
Host whatsit
   HostName whats.it
   User Thor
   Cyphers arcfour,blowfish-cbc
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/thor@whatsit
```

Then when you want to login the ssh client will over accept arc four and blowfish-cbc to the remote server.   Of course it might reject them as insecure.   So AES ciphers are recommended as they are both fast and secure.

e.g. Usage of whatsit host defined in .ssh/config
ssh whatit

or

```
sftp whatit
```

As you wish..